# How to insert <a href> into a <div> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty noob when is come to this. So, maybe for you, is piece of cake, but for me is like escalading the Everest. Please help me. Thank you!

I have this:

```html
I have this:

</br> <a class="link" href="#"><b>A</b></a>
</br> <a class="link" href="B"><b>B</b></a>
</br> <a class="link" href="C"><b>C</b></a>
</br>.....I have hundreds of links


<hr> How to transform that, into this, with javascript:

<div>
  <a class="link" href="#"><b>A</b></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="link" href="#"><b>B</b></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="link" href="#"><b>C</b></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use JSFiddle embed code on SO. You need to add your code within your question.

Comment: where is the div and where is your best try?

Comment: sorry, this is my 1st time posting here and i have strugling a bit.
i managed to find and post the snippet. i've triyed with jsfiddle but didnt work. Thank you 4 helping me.

Comment: please, explain it more... do you want just to create the divs and put the anchor inside? you will have the anchors and then dynamically add each to a div?

Comment: Have you tried it in a simple html file on your machine?

Comment: Is kinda dificult. I have like hundreds of links, so is hard to code all that links. I thought is a way to make it thru JavaScript.

Comment: Yes @Calvin. I have my html already, with hundreds of a hrefs. All I wanna do is insert that all that a hrefs in his own div.

Comment: If this is actually just a single file that you need to process once, you could (depending on the format/consistency of the file) just use a search/replace against the text.  Replace all the break tags with empty, then search/replace "<a" with "<div><a", and "</a>" with "</a></div>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you need, but try this to see if it is something like you need:

```js
function insertIntoDivs() {
            //array with all anchors that have link as class
            var allLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
            var arrayLinks = Array.from(allLinks);
            var quantLinks = arrayLinks.length;   
            //loop until all elements got hiw own div
            for (var i = 0; i < quantLinks; i++) {
                var anchor = arrayLinks[i];
                var containerDiv = document.createElement('div'); //create the div
                containerDiv.style.height = '25px';
                containerDiv.style.width = '60px';
                containerDiv.style.border = '1px solid black';
                containerDiv.appendChild(anchor); //add anchor to the div
                document.body.appendChild(containerDiv);
            }
        }
```

```html
    <a class="link" href="#">A</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">B</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">C</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">D</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">E</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">F</a>
    <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="insertIntoDivs();" value="Insert Into Divs" />
```

Comment: this is what i want, but with some difference. i don't want that button to place them in div. i wanted to be executed when page is loading.

Comment: then remove the button and modify the body tag to: 
<body onload="insertIntoDivs();">

Comment: if this answer help you or you consider it as correct, please upvote it and mark as correct in the 'V' symbol in the left

Comment: this is it. Thank you @Calvin.